# Google Charts: Bubble Charts enable legend selection

Tags: angularjs, charts, legend, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I am using angular directive for google charts 
How do i enable legend selection

i.e. 
If i click on any legend on left, it should toggle legend data on the chart

When i use a normal AreaChart or LineChart i get a function

agc-on-select="functionName(selectedItems)" which returns me the array of selection.

But in case of BubbleChart i don't get anything.

Thanks in advance.

Here is **[FIDDLE demo example](https://jsfiddle.net/eybwzrnj/1/)**

**Javascript**

```
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSeriesChart);

    function drawSeriesChart() {

      var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
        ['ID', 'Provider Bid', 'DFP Base', 'Provider',     'Revenue'],
    ['0', 0.0, 0.0, 'Unknown', 26.5],
    ['2', 0.0, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 12.88],
    ['4', 0.0, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 105.55],
    ['11', 0.0, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 441.05],
    ['19', 0.0, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 213.55],
    ['2', 0.0, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 1.65],
    ['19', 0.0, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 2.64],
    ['0', 0.8, 0.3, 'Unknown', 110],
    ['2', 0.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 131.6],
    ['4', 0.8, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 637.68],
    ['11', 0.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 1975.16],
    ['19', 0.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 985.48],
    ['2', 0.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 391.37],
    ['4', 0.8, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 299.45],
    ['11', 0.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 1969.2],
    ['19', 0.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 3140.41],
    ['0', 1.3, 0.3, 'Unknown', 22.75],
    ['2', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 37.25],
    ['4', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 70.97],
    ['11', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 138.18],
    ['19', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 101.75],
    ['2', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 426.32],
    ['4', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 82.44],
    ['11', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 1470.45],
    ['19', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 1193.6],
    ['2', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 446.49],
    ['4', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 16.14],
    ['11', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 1800.23],
    ['19', 1.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 425.57],
    ['0', 1.8, 0.3, 'Unknown', 18.25],
    ['2', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 26.57],
    ['4', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 53.84],
    ['11', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 115.13],
    ['19', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 76.38],
    ['2', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 264.38],
    ['4', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 79.57],
    ['11', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 834.74],
    ['19', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 734.89],
    ['2', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 744.86],
    ['4', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 25.41],
    ['11', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 2493.54],
    ['19', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 929.74],
    ['2', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 778.59],
    ['4', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 20.85],
    ['11', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 2660.98],
    ['19', 1.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 463.41],
    ['0', 10.3, 0.3, 'Unknown', 0.5],
    ['4', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 0.74],
    ['2', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 1.54],
    ['4', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 2.77],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 4.17],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 9.71],
    ['2', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 3.99],
    ['4', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 1.19],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 14.1],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 2.47],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 20.2],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 5.5],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 10.05],
    ['2', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 9.01],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 30.42],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 6.8],
    ['2', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 14.21],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 24.63],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 5.24],
    ['2', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 3.2],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 25.85],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 10.09],
    ['2', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 10.92],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 19.16],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 17.82],
    ['2', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 8.58],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 21.26],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 12.73],
    ['2', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 19.47],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 37.55],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 23.48],
    ['2', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 5.39],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 31.77],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 20.96],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 39.84],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 124.56],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 62.18],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 82.21],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 28.54],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 7.49],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 22.94],
    ['19', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 7.88],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 33.04],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 53.06],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 64.68],
    ['11', 10.3, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 48.49],
    ['2', 10.8, 0.8, 'Legend 1', 0.97],
    ['4', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 1.32],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 0.63],
    ['19', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 0.69],
    ['2', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 2.15],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 6.16],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 14.18],
    ['2', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 9.1],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 9.31],
    ['19', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 2.09],
    ['2', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 11.24],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 7.94],
    ['19', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 2.87],
    ['2', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 3.2],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 16.22],
    ['19', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 9.62],
    ['4', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 2', 3.64],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 3.73],
    ['2', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 16.96],
    ['19', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 12.15],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 23.03],
    ['2', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 1', 5.42],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 15.92],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 5.68],
    ['19', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 47.15],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 18.95],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 13.44],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 21.72],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 15.4],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 8.24],
    ['19', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 4', 8.29],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 69.44],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 18.34],
    ['11', 10.8, 0.0, 'Legend 3', 19.47],
    ['4', 11.3, 0.3, 'Legend 2', 0.48],
    ['2', 11.3, 0.8, 'Legend 1', 3.22],
    ['4', 11.3, 0.8, 'Legend 2', 2.14],
    ['11', 11.3, 0.8, 'Legend 3', 9.46],
    ['19', 11.3, 0.8, 'Legend 4', 5.78],
    ['2', 11.3, 0.8, 'Legend 1', 6.77],
    ['11', 11.3, 0.8, 'Legend 3', 18.53],
    ['19', 11.3, 0.8, 'Legend 4', 2.39],
    ['2', 11.3, 0.8, 'Legend 1', 3.84],
    ['11', 11.3, 0.8, 'Legend 3', 30.97],
    ['19', 9.3, 0.3, 'Legend 4', 14.15],
    ['2', 9.3, 0.3, 'Legend 1', 8.67],
    ['11', 9.3, 0.3, 'Legend 3', 52.32],
    ['19', 9.3, 0.3, 'Legend 4', 5.11],
]);

      var options = {
        title: 'test',
        hAxis: {title: 'X Axis'},
        vAxis: {title: 'y Axis'},
        bubble: {textStyle: {fontSize: 11}}
      };

      var chart = new google.visualization.BubbleChart(document.getElementById('series_chart_div'));
      chart.draw(data, options);
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
   <div id="series_chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google chart consider the elements in first row except 0 index as the legends,

in case of bubble chart there are  two types of legends one is based on color variation and other as unique value of index 3 in you case.

But in both cases the callback on `selectedItems` does not work as it is still considering the row 0 headings as legends, that's why it not working.

Try this:

Make your own legend by calculating unique of index 3
and mark

`legend: { 
            position: 'none'
        },`

in options  and use custom legends instead that way you will get you own events.